# Can't install google-fluentd on Amazon Linux 2023

Tags: google-cloud-platform, amazon-linux-2023

I'm facing an issue when install google-fluentd on Amazon Linux 2023. The error is showing error with redhat-lsb-core.

```
[root]# sudo yum install -y google-fluentd-1.9.*
Last metadata expiration check
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides redhat-lsb-core needed by google-fluentd-1.9.0-1.el6.x86_64
  - nothing provides redhat-lsb-core needed by google-fluentd-1.9.1-1.el6.x86_64
  - nothing provides redhat-lsb-core needed by google-fluentd-1.9.2-1.el6.x86_64
  - nothing provides redhat-lsb-core needed by google-fluentd-1.9.3-1.el6.x86_64
  - nothing provides redhat-lsb-core needed by google-fluentd-1.9.4-1.el6.x86_64
  - nothing provides redhat-lsb-core needed by google-fluentd-1.9.5-1.el6.x86_64
  - nothing provides redhat-lsb-core needed by google-fluentd-1.9.6-1.el6.x86_64
  - nothing provides redhat-lsb-core needed by google-fluentd-1.9.7-1.amzn1.x86_64
  - nothing provides redhat-lsb-core needed by google-fluentd-1.9.8-1.amzn1.x86_64
  - nothing provides redhat-lsb-core needed by google-fluentd-1.9.9-1.amzn1.x86_64
  - nothing provides redhat-lsb-core needed by google-fluentd-1.9.10-1.amzn1.x86_64
  - nothing provides redhat-lsb-core needed by google-fluentd-1.9.11-1.amzn1.x86_64
  - nothing provides redhat-lsb-core needed by google-fluentd-1.9.12-1.amzn1.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

Thanks for any support!

I tried to install google-fluentd on amazon linux 2023 but it not work.

Comment: AFAIK Amazon Linux is not supported. Use an OS from the supported list: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/logging#supported_operating_systems

Comment: any other way to install google-fluentd from tar file? Does anyone do this?